# Angularjs ng-options: Utilizar propriedade do objeto como valor ao invés do índice do array

Tags: json, angularjs, html-select

No código abaixo, Angularjs `ng-options` renderiza o valor mas registra a posição no array e não o valor.

Recebo o seguinte json:

```
[{"iduniforme":1,
  "nomeuniforme":"Uniforme 5 itens",
  "itensuniforme":[{...},{...},{...},{...},{...}]},
 {"iduniforme":2,
  "nomeuniforme":"Uniforme 7 itens",
  "itensuniforme":{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...}]}]
```

Usando o ng-options do Angularjs, monto meu select:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Uniforme da Equipe</label>
   <select class="form-control" name="uniforme" id="uniforme"
   ng-model="uniforme" ng-options="x.nomeuniforme for x in listaUniformes">
   <option value="">Selecione o uniforme</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Consigo renderizar normalmente, ou seja as opções aparecem corretamente, porém, ah porém, quando submeto o form o valor registrado é a posição dentro do array [0] ou [1] e não o valor em "nomeuniforme" que nesse caso seria "Uniforme 5 itens" ou "Uniforme 7 itens".

Como resolvo isso? Necessito registrar o valor "Uniforme 5 itens" ou "Uniforme 7 itens" na base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não funcionou com seus exemplos.

Consegui em [How to set the value property in AngularJS' ng-options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139152/how-to-set-the-value-property-in-angularjs-ng-options)

Adicionando track by, o código ficou assim:

```
ng-options="x.nomeuniforme for x in listaUniformes track by x.nomeuniforme">
```

Origado pela ajuda. Abraço.

Answer (score 0):

Inclua a cláusula AS para ajudar o AngularJS a determinar o par valor/texto a ser utilizado. No seu caso, substitua

```
<select class="form-control" name="uniforme" id="uniforme"
   ng-model="uniforme" ng-options="x.nomeuniforme for x in listaUniformes">
```

por

```
<select class="form-control" name="uniforme" id="uniforme"
   ng-model="uniforme" ng-options="x.iduniforme as x.nomeuniforme for x in listaUniformes">
```

caso queira referenciar a propriedade `IdUniforme`, ou

```
<select class="form-control" name="uniforme" id="uniforme"
   ng-model="uniforme" ng-options="x.nomeuniforme as x.nomeuniforme for x in listaUniformes">
```

caso queira referenciar a propriedade `nomeuniforme`.