# ANGULARJS- NG-OPTIONS

Tags: angularjs

tenho a seguint combo:

```
<select data-ng-model="dadosAddContaCamara.camara" data-ng-options="item.codigo as item.descricao for item in controller.listarCamara">
```

preciso que o model dadosAddContaCamara.camara passe como objeto os valores
item.codigo as item.descricao, porem so vai como string.alguma dica?

Comment: Talvez isso ajude:

[http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69933/angularjs-ng-options-utilizar-propriedade-do-objeto-como-valor-ao-inv%C3%A9s-do-%C3%ADndi][1]


  [1]: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69933/angularjs-ng-options-utilizar-propriedade-do-objeto-como-valor-ao-inv%C3%A9s-do-%C3%ADndi

Comment: resolveu o problema!! valeu!

Answer (score 1):

Quando você escreve em ng-options "item.codigo as item.descricao", está dizendo para o angular "quero o código do item mas exiba a descrição do item". Se a sua função listarCamara retorna uma lista de objetos, exemplo:

```
var lista = [{"codigo":"1","descricao":"item 1"}
            ,{"codigo":"2","descricao":"item 2"}];
```

Você pode obter o objeto com "item as item descricao" em vez de "item.codigo as item.descricao".

Boa sorte!